# Python array indexing within for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

This program aims to generate a resistance value according to:

[image]

(Given an array of resistances and temperatures).

In order to obtain the current value of resistance, the equation requires an initial resistance and initial temperature values (R_0, T_0) from the array. It also requires the successive value of temperature (T) from the array.

My try:

```
r_model=[]
for r in r_values:
    result = r*(1+2.9*(t_values[r+1]-t_values[r]))
    fit2.append(result)
r_model = array(r_model)
```

My error:

```
index out of bounds
```

Comment: Why are you looping over r_values which you are trying to compute rather than the t_values which are known?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the array index while processing a `for` loop, you can use `enumerate`:

```
r_model=[]
for (index, r) in enumerate(r_values):
    result = r*(1+2.9*(t_values[index+1]-t_values[index]))
    fit2.append(result)
r_model = array(r_model)
```

If `r_values` is `[1500,2500,0.0001]`, then `enumerate(r_values)` will iterate through this sequence:

```
(0, 1500)
(1,2500)
(2,0.0001)
```

And at each step, you can use the index (0,1, and 2) to get the proper value from the `t_values` list.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
r_values = arange(1500,2500,0.0001)    #R_0 values
for r in r_values:
# . . .
    t_values[r+1]
```

So the first time through the loop you wind up with:

```
t_values[1501]
```

But t_values only has 3 elements.

Comment: Yeah, sorry the arrays are something I wrote up quickly. I actually take the arrays from a .txt files with elements of the same dimensions. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: It doesn't matter they are the same dimension - you are indexing with the value, not the index.

Comment: And at any rate if the _were_ the same dimensions you will still get a problem because of the `[r+1]` index... T array must be larger than r array.

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing t with the value of r rather than the index. `for ri, r in r_values` I believe, is the syntax - then use `ri` to index `t_values`

See also [Accessing the index in Python 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops)

Another problem in your code: your equation talks about difference with T0, but you take the difference `t_values[r+1]-t_values[r]`. Should be `t_values[ri]-t_values[0]` ?